# `cabal install vector` fails

Tags: haskell, cabal

```
$ cabal install vector                                                


Resolving dependencies... Error: cabal: Could not resolve dependencies: 
[__0] trying: vector-0.13.0.0 (user goal) 
[__1] trying: primitive-0.6.4.0 (dependency of vector) 
[__2] next goal: base (dependency of vector) 
[__2] rejecting: base-4.16.3.0/installed-4.16.3.0 (conflict: primitive => base>=4.5 && <4.13) 
[__2] rejecting: base-4.10.0.0, base-4.9.1.0, base-4.9.0.0, base-4.8.2.0, base-4.8.1.0, base-4.8.0.0, base-4.7.0.2, base-4.7.0.1, base-4.7.0.0, base-4.6.0.1, base-4.6.0.0, base-4.5.1.0, base-4.5.0.0, base-4.4.1.0, base-4.4.0.0, base-4.3.1.0, base-4.3.0.0, base-4.2.0.2, base-4.2.0.1, base-4.2.0.0, base-4.1.0.0, base-4.0.0.0, base-3.0.3.2, base-3.0.3.1 (constraint from non-upgradeable package requires installed instance)
[__2] fail (backjumping, conflict set: base, primitive, vector) After searching the rest of the dependency tree exhaustively, these were the goals I've had most trouble fulfilling: base, vector, primitive

$ ghc --version && cabal --version    
                                                                                                                                                                                     
The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 8.10.7
cabal-install version 3.8.1.0
compiled using version 3.8.1.0 of the Cabal library
```

I'm not sure, but it seems `primitive` and `base` are conflict packages?

```
$ uname -a                                                                                                                                                                                                               
Darwin MacBook-Pro-2.local 21.2.0 Darwin Kernel Version 21.2.0: Sun Nov 28 20:28:41 PST 2021; root:xnu-8019.61.5~1/RELEASE_ARM64_T6000 arm64
```

`-v3` output is pasted here:
https://pastebin.com/sfNWXB8R

```
$ ghc-pkg list
/usr/local/Cellar/ghc/8.10.7_1/lib/ghc-8.10.7/package.conf.d
    Cabal-3.2.1.0
    array-0.5.4.0
    base-4.14.3.0
    binary-0.8.8.0
    bytestring-0.10.12.0
    containers-0.6.5.1
    deepseq-1.4.4.0
    directory-1.3.6.0
    exceptions-0.10.4
    filepath-1.4.2.1
    ghc-8.10.7
    ghc-boot-8.10.7
    ghc-boot-th-8.10.7
    ghc-compact-0.1.0.0
    ghc-heap-8.10.7
    ghc-prim-0.6.1
    ghci-8.10.7
    haskeline-0.8.2
    hpc-0.6.1.0
    integer-gmp-1.0.3.0
    libiserv-8.10.7
    mtl-2.2.2
    parsec-3.1.14.0
    pretty-1.1.3.6
    process-1.6.13.2
    rts-1.0.1
    stm-2.5.0.1
    template-haskell-2.16.0.0
    terminfo-0.4.1.4
    text-1.2.4.1
    time-1.9.3
    transformers-0.5.6.2
    unix-2.7.2.2
    xhtml-3000.2.2.1
```

Comment: `[__2] rejecting: base-4.16.3.0/installed-4.16.3.0 (conflict: primitive => base>=4.5 && <4.13) ` That version of `base` corresponds to GHC 9.2.4. GHC 8.10.7 is supposed to have `base` 4.14.3.0.

Comment: What happens if you run `cabal update` and then try again?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica It always shows `Downloading the latest package list from mirrors.ustc.edu.cn`

Comment: That's supposed to pull from `hackage.haskell.org`. Revert the changes you made to Cabal's configuration and then try again.